# Как передать несколько изображений в одном url

Tags: url

Интересует как можно передать несколько фотографий в одной ссылке, чтобы в последствии их можно было скачать.

Как вот здесь параметры передают, только в нашем случае ссылки на [фото](https://coderoad.ru/10943635/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D0%BF%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%BD%D0%B5%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BA%D0%BE-%D0%BF%D0%B0%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%B5%D1%82%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2-%D0%B2-URL):

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Просто упаковать их в zip-архив.